# Как отобразить данные из связанной таблицы в форме редактирования?

Tags: yii2

**Имеется:**

- таблица **User** с полями **id** *(id юзера)* и **org** *(id организации из табл Org)*, модель User;
- таблица **Org** с полями **id** *(id организации)*, **name** *(название организации)*, модель Org;
- в модели User настроена связь *(сделано через gii)*: 
      `public function getOrg0()
      {
          return $this->hasOne(Org::className(), ['id' => 'org']);
      }`
- форма для редактирования записи таблицы User: ( app/modules/users/views/user/_form.php) в которой есть строка для редактирования поля

  `/* @var $model app\modules\users\models\User */
  .....
  field($model, 'org0.name')->textInput() ?>`

**На выходе ошибка:**
Getting unknown property: app\modules\users\models\User::org0.name
Если пишем так
`field($model, 'org')->textInput() ?>`
то на выходе id организации из таблицы User.
Как правильно написать строку чтобы на выходе было название организации из таблицы Org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам следует сделать чуть по-другому.

У `$model` обратиться по имени связки в модели, а имя поля указываете уже без нее:

`<?= $form->field($model->org0, 'name')->textInput() ?>`

Comment: это работает!!!! Спасибо большое за помощь!